# Why does changing ModelEntity scale seem to affect position as well?

Tags: augmented-reality, realitykit, ios-animations

I have been playing with `session(session: didUpdate frame: ARFrame)` and trying to make a ModelEntity move and scale at the same time. I start the movement by calling:

```
model.move(to: [-1, 0, 0], relativeTo: model.anchor, duration: 1)
```

Then in the `session(session: didUpdate frame: ARFrame)` I watch the ModelEntity move. But when I also try to scale down the ModelEntity by 50%, the ModelEntity's position goes to `[-27, 0, 0]` (expected is [-1, 0, 0]).

```
let entDistanceFromAnchor = simd_distance(transform.columns.3, entity.anchor!.transform.matrix.columns.3)
entity.setScale([0.5,0.5,0.5], relativeTo: entity.anchor)
```

Why is changing the scale causing the position to change as well? Is there a way to change the models scale without changing the position?